# Armel debian packages

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-fuerte, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've recently tried to install ROS onto a Linaro system (12.01 or 12.03 I believe). I've been following the generic ROS installation tutorial, and I run into problems when running this command.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ros-comm
```

Apt claims that there are no packages found. A quick "apt-cache search ros-" confirms that no packages are around. I've successfully installed ROS this way in the past.

According to the [Debian build status](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html), there doesn't seem like ARM packages are being built/hosted anymore. Are they still supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35766/armel-debian-packages/) by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the previous infrastructure only a few specific releases built a small number of packages.  The effort for that small set of packages was to high to support.  In the new generation build system adding armel support should be easier.  It's ticketed at https://github.com/willowgarage/catkin-debs/issues/8 and will be added when time is available.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on 2012-06-06**:
Thanks for the response. Catkin looks promising. Just out of curiosity, will the Catkin system simplify cross compilation? I have a few nodes that I'm native compiling that I'd like to cross compile.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-06**:
Yes cross compiling with Catkin is much easier.  You just use the standard cmake settings for cross compling.  And with out of source builds you can compile different binary targets from the same source tree.